# ItemsSource Data Binding Not Binding Properly

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I am fairly new to xaml and C# data bindings. I am attempting to bind a Picker to an IList using ItemsSource, ItemDisplayBinding, and SelectedItem. The Picker binds to the IList, but it doesn't display the correct information.

I've looked at several resources, and the Monkey App picker was a pretty big help. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/MonkeyAppPicker

I tried replicating what he had done, but to no avail.

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Mills}" 
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMill, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

```
namespace TDSDesktop
{
    public class PurchaseAgreementBindings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class Mill
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address1 { get; set; }
            public string Address2 { get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
        }

        public static class MillData
        {
            public static IList<Mill> Mills { get; private set; }

            static MillData()
            {
                Mills  = new List<Mill>();
                Mills.Add(new Mill
                {
                    Name = "Name1",
                    Address1 = "123",
                    Address2 = "City, State Zip",
                    Phone = "555-555-5555"
                });
                Mills.Add(new Mill
                {
                    Name = "Name2",
                    Address1 = "456",
                    Address2 = "City, State Zip",
                    Phone = "888-888-8888"
                });
            }
        }

        public IList<Mill> Mills { get { return MillData.Mills; } }

        Mill selectedMill;
        public Mill SelectedMill
        {
            get { return selectedMill; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedMill != value)
                {
                    selectedMill = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Theoretically, the picker should display two values (Name1 and Name2) because I have the ItemDisplayBinding set to Name. However, when I run my program, the values are "TDSDesktop.PurchaseAgreementBindings+Mill" for both. Clearly I am missing something. If someone could explain how I need to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Also, your `ItemDisplayBinding` binding doesn't seem to make sense. It attempts to bind against the `Mill.Name` property of an item in the ItemsSource collection. However, the items in this collection are _Mill_ objects, which don't have a `Mill.Name` property, but rather just a `Name` property.

Comment: Okay, you edited the code in the question. But now the question is: Did you also edit your actual real code accordingly and tried building + running your program again? ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo yes, I edited it back to its original form in my project. I accidentally copied the wrong xaml code. However, both "versions" resulted in the same issue

Comment: Now, my knowledge of Xamarin is way too limited, but i would expect that `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"` would work. I am just grasping at straws now, but what if your move the _Mill_ outside of the _PurchaseAgreementBindings_ class (i.e., un-nest it). Does it improve the situation then?

Comment: @elgonzo you mentioned something earlier about the Data/BindingContext for Mills, but I can't find the comment.

Comment: I deleted that comment, as it was superfluous and pointless. I wrote it just considering the title of your question (which mislead me a little), without noticing that you actually saw "TDSDesktop.PurchaseAgreementBindings+Mill" in your picker -- which means that the ItemsSource binding itself actually works (my fault for not reading your entire question description attentively before writing that now-deleted comment)

Comment: @elgonzo When I moved the Mill class outside of the PurchaseAgreementBindings, the picker showed "TDSDesktop.Mill" instead

Comment: Weird. Just for trouble-shooting purposes, add an ToString() override to your _Mill_ class like `public override string ToString() { return "MonkeyBusiness"; }` and then run your program again and tell me what you see in the picker...

Comment: @elgonzo Interesting, the picker values changed to "MonkeyBusiness". I don't fully understand what that means though or how I can use that

Comment: It means that the ItemDisplayBinding binding in your XAML is somehow prevented from becoming effective. (If there is no ItemDisplayBinding or that binding is not successful, the Picker/ItemsControl resorts to show the string representation of an item as provided by the item's ToString() method (which, if not overridden, by default returns the type name of the object)

Comment: The only other two things i can think of that (1) might screw with the ItemDisplayBinding is that somewhere in your code you mess around with the Picker in some way, deactivating or replacing the ItemDisplayBinding as set by the XAML... Check your code-behind for anything that might be related to Picker (or ItemsSource)...

Comment: (2) The second thing is that perhaps in your XAML code you have declared two or more pickers (intentionally or accidentally, i can't tell), but you edited/corrected the binding of the "wrong" picker (not the picker you are looking at when running your program)

Comment: By the way, you can remove the ToString() override again, and move the _Mill_ class back inside _PurchaseAgreementBindings_, if you like...